# Django search query in JSON data

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

Unsupported lookup 'name' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.

Error:
FieldError at /search/

Unsupported lookup 'name' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.

views.py

```
    query = request.GET.get('search')
    if query:
        product_list = product_list.filter(
            Q(product_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(brand__brand_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(model__name__icontains=query) |
            Q(gtin_no__icontains=query) |
            Q(oem_no__icontains=query) |
            Q(tag__icontains=query)
        )
```

models.py

```
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=300)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ProductCategory', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100)
    brand = models.ManyToManyField('Brand', null=True, max_length=100)
    model = JSONField(null=True, max_length=10000)
    product_code = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    gtin_no = JSONField(blank=True, max_length=10000)
    oem_no = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10000)
    tag = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10000, default=None)
```

Example model JSON data:

```
{
    "data": "[['Car Parts', 'Ssangyong'], ['Industrial Parts', 'Lombardini'], ['Mercedes-Benz Sprinter', 'Sprinter OM 601, OM 602 DE LA']]"
}
```

Example GTIN JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        "4047755219970"
    ]
}
```

Example OEM JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        "624 320 0028",
        "625 320 0028"
    ]
}
```

Sometimes this JSON data can be empty.

```
{
    "data": [
        "None"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing this:

```
query = request.GET.get('search')
    if query:
        product_list = product_list.filter(
            Q(product_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(brand__brand_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(model__name__icontains=query) |
            Q(gtin_no__icontains=query) |
            Q(oem_no__icontains=query) |
            Q(tag__icontains=query)
        )
```

You can put `product_list` to `context` like this:

```
context = {
   "products": product_list # <- you can name it whatever you want.
}
```

Then do this to pass the context to whatever html file you are working with:

```
render(request, "path/to/htmlfile", context=context, status=200) # by the way, you can set status code here.
```

**EDIT**

I think you can just remove `__name` from `Q(model__name__icontains=query)` because the error says it causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks but I wrote this code already. I'm not searched my query in JSON data.

Comment: FieldError at /search/

Unsupported lookup 'name' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Could you show us your full error? Please add the error in your question because it's very hard to read in comment.